# Is $W^{1,2}_0$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I came across the term $W^{1,2}_0$. Just a quick question on what the 0 means and is it a Hilbert space?

---

I know $W^{1,2}$ is a Hilbert space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ with respect to $ ||.||_{1,2}$ and is thought of as the space of Sobolev functions with zero boundary value. As closure of a linear subspace in a Hilbert space it is a Hilbert space, too.

See, e.g.,  [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space)

Comment: $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is an Hilbert space for the $\sqrt{||.||_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}^{\ 2} + ||.||_{W^{1,2}(\partial \Omega)}^{\ 2}}$ norm not for the $||.||_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}$ norm for which it is not complete ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Traces

Comment: @user1952009 I don't understand what the question is. If you have a Hilbert space (which is complete) then a closed linear subspace is complete, too. I'm not sure the norm you've written down in useful here, usually you'd look at $L^p(\partial \Omega)$ as the target space for the so called trace operator on $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, not at $W^{1,p}(\partial \Omega)$. This is also explained in the Wikipedia article and, in addition, here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator. In case of $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ the image of the trace operator is zero, so your norm reduces to the $W^{1,2}$ norm.